# Making an object inside a NSMutableArray into another array isn't working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this code:

```
secondArray = [firstArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

The object at index 1 is already an NSMutableArray inside `[firstArray]`. The problem is that when I change `secondArray`, the `firstArray` also changes.

How can I stop this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'first array is also changing'? Do you mean the values within the array? Can you provide some more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not trying to replace the firstArray, i'm trying to make the secondArray the same value as the NSMutableArray at index 1. But it's changing that array inside firstArray too when i change secondArray.

Comment: So basically, you want to change the values in secondArray without impacting the values in firstArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to keep it from changing is to copy the array instead of set it.  I had that problem before, and this is what did the trick for me

EDIT: just so I don't give you poor information, I'm going to change this to a more generalized version:

```
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[[firstArray objectAtIndex:1] count];
[secondArray addObjectsFromArray:[firstArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

This should better fit your situation.  I have tested it twice to be sure by creating arrays and cloning them, then modifying the clones to see they are the only objects being modified

Comment: This doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Comment: this will copy the array and not the array's values, if you change the values - for example if the value is an object and you set a property of it, it wont solve the problem, you also need to copy each value you want to change

Comment: This is a good point.  I was under the assumption that `secondArray` was being initialized previously.  In that case, I suggest using the answer given by @cs

Comment: For me this says NSMutableArray may not respond to -addobjectswitharray.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo.  I apologize.  I'll fix it.  It should be `addObjectsFromArray`

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to do something along the lines of the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [firstArray objectAtIndex:1] copyItems:YES];
```

This will create a new array and copy each item in the first array to the newly created array instead of retaining them as is currently the case in your code.

There is one caveat, though: All of the objects in the first array need to conform to the NSCopying protocol for this to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works or not as when i try to do a replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject: on the secondArray, it causes a crash. NSLogging the object in question shows it exists. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code. What error are you getting?